# Is creating a table to store one single row sign of bad programming?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am working on a java project that connects to a DB and i am thinking of a way to store an "admin password" in the database to grant the access to "admin methods" in my java program.
is creating a table just to store this password so that you can retrieve it and even changing it when you get it right in the program a sign of bad programming?
 ( ex: insert psw---->retrieve psw from database ----> if its the same you are switched to an admin list of actions, one of them is the changing of this psw)

Comment: Although not necessarily the right format question for SO, here are some thoughts: If this is the only thing you will use the DB for, consider using environment variables for storing credentials, as it eliminates quite a few hurdles involved in getting access to a DB securely. If however, you already use a DB for other application needs, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no.

When data doesn't fit into the other relational tables and you can't imagine to put the data in another Table, go for it.

You can always change the Structure and the programming that accesses the data, if in future the database structure  has to change and  you find  the opportunity to save the data elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

If your question is really just, "is it a bad design practice to use a database (**edit**: or database table) to hold only one piece--or a few pieces--of data", I would say probably not. Databases are a place to hold data, and they very easily scale. You might at some point need to hold more data, and in the future a lot more data, and databases do that very efficiently.

Is it overkill for a single piece of data? Probably, but I doubt you'd end up just storing that one piece there. If it's just one user (you) you don't need a database, but rather secure credentials or an application that only you can access. But assuming it's not just for you, you'll probably find a lot of other things that are helpful to store there.

However, the question you didn't really ask but should be more interested in, is *can* you do this securely? The answer there is a lot more dubious. Even very well-designed, complex user access systems have vulnerabilities. It is difficult to account for all of the common vulnerabilities and design flaws. How will you handle password encryption? Brute force attack denial? Attacks that use the variance in the *response time* of your database to different passwords to hone in on the password?

I'm not a security expert, but I know enough to know that, and to leave security related systems to those who specialize in them. I suggest you do the same.

If you absolutely need to have a user-authentication process, use a system that already exists. It's not that hard, and a lot more secure, to tie into an authentication system. If you don't absolutely need to, and this is all just for you or one other user, just avoid the security problem and don't develop it as a public system that you log into over the application.

**Edit:** Rereading your question, you already have a database but are asking about an additional table in it. My answer holds -- it's not a bad practice, but storing of a password in it is still very risky if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: the actual project is for an exam in my university about software engineer, you were really accurate with your answer and i thank you for that, but security is nothing i should care about for this project ( i should've pointed that out maybe in the question). THANK YOU!

Comment: Ah, okay. Although, if you were my student and did that in your project, I would take a whole letter grade off for it, with a big red note that said, "Never store unencrypted passwords in a database"